# NetworkInfo.isAvailable() for Ethernet is always false even if Ethernet is available and connected

Tags: android, networking, ethernet

Here is the code:

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo info = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
Log.e("TEST","=================Info================\n"+info.toString());
```

The logcat looks like

```
E/TEST    ( 2113): =================Info================
E/TEST    ( 2113): NetworkInfo: type: ETHERNET[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason:    (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false
```

Do you think this is weird? Not available but connected...

Comment: Here are the list of solutions http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/Connectivity.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to check you network connectivity

```
 public boolean isNetworkOnline() {
boolean status=false;
try{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        status= true;
    }else {
        netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
        if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
            status= true;
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();  
    return false;
}
return status;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Nishant. But the problem lies in that some applications are judging the connectivity by this kind of logic:
    
    NetworkInfo localNetworkInfo1 = ((ConnectivityManager)paramContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(!localNetworkInfo1.isAvailable())
        return false;//return not connected

Then these applications will not run normally while there is Ethernet connection but no Wi-Fi connection. Because in this case isAvailable() always return false as Ethernet is the ACTIVE network.